# With angular component and ui-router, can a single controller have multiple templates?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-components, angular-component-router

In a **component** I would like to associate templates to CRUD actions, but use a single controller that handles data for all all of them. Does this make sense with angular components, or should I use several components ?
How would the ui-router state configuration look like ?

**EDIT**:
Components have templates, and ui-router states too. I am confused about the articulation of those 2 concepts.

**EDIT 2**:
trying to clarify my understanding so far :

- component are controller + template + bindings. Controller can be omitted.
- states are url + template + controller or url + component. Controller can be omitted.

So it seems that components are taking away some of the responsabilities that use to belong to ui-router.

My goal here:

```
 - url1 --> controller foo + template x;
 - url2 --> controller foo + template y;
 - url3 --> controller foo + template z;
```

should I do :

components:

```
component x --> controller foo + template x;
component y --> controller foo + template y;
component z --> controller foo + template z;
```

and then routing:

```
url 1 --> component x
url 2 --> component y
url 3 --> component z
```

?

**EDIT 3:**
quote from https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component :

"In a component-based application, every view is a component"

quote from https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component :

"The component model enforces separation of concerns and encapsulation by using an isolate scope. Data from parent scopes can no longer be directly accessed. Instead, it needs to be explicitly wired in"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Your `ui-router` config would look something like this: (Multiple `state`s having same controllers.)

```
.state('add', {
    url: '/add',
    templateUrl: 'templates/add.html',
    controller: 'contactCtrl'
})
.state('edit', {
    url: '/edit',
    templateUrl: 'templates/edit.html',
    controller: 'contactCtrl'
})
```

Here's a [**working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/789Ks/365/) of having multiple states and templates using same controller.

---

**Edit**: You don't have to use `components`. Why create three different extra components while you can achieve the same thing without them? I would still recommend the approach I mentioned above. Getting the same outcome with lesser code should always be chosen. :)

Quoting [Eric Elliot](https://twitter.com/_ericelliott) on twitter,

> Code is temporary. It exists while it is useful.
>   If code is replaced by better code, good!
>   If code can be deleted, celebrate!

Comment: thanks but I asked this specifically about angular components. Components define a template too, so I am confused between ui-router template a component template.

Comment: mmmh I suppose this is a very relevant question apparently I have       "angular": "^1.5.2",  "angular-ui-router": "^0.3.1" which trnalsates into 0.3.2 installed. I'll try ui-router version 1.0 alpha. now.

Comment: actually I am confused now. There is angular-ui-router && ui-router. I guess one is a fork of the other into angular. if you have any recommendation I'll take it. Whatever is best for use with angular components.

Comment: @Olivvv `angular-ui-router`

Comment: I'd recommend using components instead of using controllers and I disagree with your quote by Eric Elliot in this instance. Purposefully using deprecated concepts because 'It's easier this way and it's less work' is also known as *laziness*.

Comment: @DanPantry I sort of agree with you but since all components are using same controller but different templates, I was leaning towards *this* approach

Comment: @DanPantry would you share your suggested code/architecture then ?

Comment: @tanmay I am currently updating my knowledge to es6/ng1.5, so every step is more painful than with a well know older stack. But here, I am confident that components have been thought with crud in mind. There must be a right way, I just don't see it clearly as for now, but I want to find out. Also, I dont really have choice to not use components, it is a company guideline. They have the vision, I implement...

Answer (score 0):

Your state provider will look like this

**JS code**

```
        $stateProvider
      .state('report', {
        views: {
          'filters': {
            templateUrl: 'report-filters.html',
            controller: 'ctrl'
          },
          'tabledata': {
            templateUrl: 'report-table.html',
            controller: 'ctrl'
          },
          'graph': {
            templateUrl: 'report-graph.html',
            controller: 'ctrl'
          }
        }
      })
```

in single state you can load multiple views

**HTML**

```
  <body>
    <div ui-view="filters"></div>
    <div ui-view="tabledata"></div>
    <div ui-view="graph"></div>
  </body>
```

refer [multiple views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

Comment: As said, I ask specifically for a components architecture. Components have templates as well.

Comment: so you can add there also

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('', [])
  // Route handler touches this
  .component('route1', {
    template: `<shared-behaviour>
      <route-view-1></route-view-1>
    </shared-behaviour>`
  })
  // This is a purely visual component that links actions with the shared behaviour component
  .component('routeView1', {
    require: {
      shared: '^sharedBehaviour'
    },
    template: '<button ng-click="$ctrl.onClick()></button>',
    controller: class RouteView2Ctrl {
      onClick() {
        this.shared.onSharedClick()
      }
    }
  })
  // Contains the shared behaviour that is shared across the multiple routes
  .component('sharedBehaviour', {
    // Tell Angular to render children passed to this component
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    controller: class SharedBehaviourCtrl {
      onSharedClick() {
        /// do something
      }
    }
  })
  // Newest version of UI-Router
  .state('route1', {
    component: 'route1'
  })
```

Further to our comments, you could use something like the above. It's pretty verbose, but that's Angular 1.5 for you. Haven't tested that it works, but it's a basic idea of how it *might* work.

The main take away being that you have the `route1` component which only handles linking route stuff (like the url, resolves, etc) and passes that information to its children (of which there aren't any).

`routeView1` just renders how the route would work, and uses `require` to talk to some parent API that is shared (you could also use one-way bindings for this if you wanted, but with lots of methods this leads to a messy template).

`sharedBehaviour` only contains the shared behaviour you want renders any child passed to it.

---

This *is* admittedly pretty messy and I would *prefer* that you instead used one-way bindings for `route-view-1` and handled the linking in `shared-behaviour`, but this might be quite a bit of repetition. You could use some transclusion magic to solve that, but it's.. not really worth it.

I would *really* recommend against sharing controllers like other answerers have suggested. In Angular 2 and above, a controller *is* the component. You share behaviour there by doing something similar to what I have done (or by using one-way bindings with callbacks) and using composition.

---

BTW as mentioned in my answer, newer versions of UI-Router for Angular 1.5 allow you to specify a component to be rendered rather than a template. See [here](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component) for more info.

Comment: I am studying your answer. By "newer versions" you mean "1.0.0-rc.1", right ? https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/releases

Comment: Do I understand right that you recommend to have seperate "read", "create", "update" components ?

Comment: I'd recommend you have a component for the display of each route. You could have a single component with all of the shared behaviour if you wanted, although the more you describe this, the more it sounds like you want a service that handles the CRUD operations.